# How to add startup filter to Azure Function App to do some work between Dependency Injection and all triggers start?

Tags: azure, azure-functions

I have some configuration data from App Config need be validated before business logic of triggers can consume it. If there is validation error from the data, we need to block the startup of the function to prevent data corruption and let deployment monitor be aware of this and skip switching the production and staging environment.

The reason I have to do between these two stages is that this is a legacy project, and the configuration data binding and class are initialized via Dependency Injection. The minimal change I can do to add this new configuration data type and logic is reusing current flow.

So how can I add some filter like startup filter of Azure Web App into Azure Function App?

We have another Web App project using startup filter. I added similar code into Azure Function App but it does not run during startup.

Comment: are you using in-process function app ?

Comment: @Thomas yes, it's an in-process function app.